# Lindeberg-Feller Condition, problems with proof

Tags: probability

I try to understand the proof of the Feller Condition.

The theorem is:

> Let $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $L^2$ random
> variables, which  fullfills the Lindeberg condition $$L_n =\frac{1}{S_n^2} \sum_{k = 1}^n E(X_k^2  I_{[|X_k| > \epsilon S_n]})\to 0  \,\,\,\text{for}\,\,\, n \to \infty.$$
>
> Then follows:
>
> 1. $\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{|X_k|}{n}    \quad\underrightarrow{P}\quad\mathcal{N}(0,1),$
> 2. $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \max_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{Var(X_k)}{S_n^2} \,=\, 0.$

I have problems with the proof of 1.

Proof: Let $\epsilon >0$. Then we have:

$$P\left(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{|X_k|}{n} > \epsilon\right)  \leq \sum_{k=1}^n P\left(|X_k| > \epsilon S_n\right).$$

(this step is clear, the sum over all is greater than the maximum over all.)

$$= \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\Omega} I_{[|X_k|> \epsilon S_n]} \, dP.$$

I think in this step we use the fact that we can write the probability as expectation with the indicator function (tell me if I am wrong). And with the next step I have problems:

$$\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{[|X_k| > \epsilon S_n]}  \frac{|X_k|^2}{\epsilon^2 S_n^2} \, dP.$$

If needed I can add the rest of the proof. Can anyone explain me the last inequality please. Where do the squares come from?

Comment: Is it something with the Chebyshev in equality?